# Invalid rgb arg 'x' while converting string to float

Tags: python, string, numpy, matplotlib

im trying to plot a data .... they contain commas and after converting them to floats i get error.

data sample '   0,8750044   '

this is part of the script

```
for row in data:
    xvalue.append(row[0])
    yvalue.append(float(row[1].replace(',','.')))
    yerro.append(float(row[3].replace(',','.')))
 plt.errorbar( xvalue, yvalue, yerr=yerro, label='error', ecolor='xkcd:salmon', elinewidth=1.5, capsize=5, errorevery=1)
  ax= plt.gca()
  ax.set_xlim([0,110])
```

i get following error;

```
    ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "x"
     to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "x"
     could not convert string to float: 'x'
```

i printed all 3 rows ...results down here

```
 row 1 ->  [35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0, 55.0, 60.0, 65.0, 70.0, 75.0, 80.0, 85.0, 90.0, 
95.0, 100.0] 

 row 2 ->   [1.117702, 0.9835718, 0.8750044, 0.787232, 0.7157482, 0.6559332, 0.6059028, 
0.562483, 0.5250466, 0.4921584, 0.4633862, 0.4377058, 0.4145508, 0.3934362] 

 row 3 ->   [0.007960752, 0.000118388, 0.000210205, 0.000125529, 0.0004768, 
0.000318498, 0.000239502, 8.58429e-05, 0.000172489, 0.000163555, 0.00041402, 
0.000548504, 0.000116907, 0.000159586]
```

if the rows are fine... then there is something wrong plt.errorbar() 
can someone plz explain what went wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: Could you share an example of `data`? Maybe u missed `replace(',', '.')` in the `xvalue.append(row[0])`, since it tells you that smth is wrong with `xvalue` argument.

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and in the except suite print out relevant data - like the thing that is being converted; look at what got printed; figure out what is wrong with it; work backwards from there.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using?  You can check with `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)`  If your version is too old, it will not have the 'xkcd' colors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557609/2823755

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser scripting in Python 3.5 (spyder). Matplotlib  version 1.5.1

Comment: @wwii found out there is something fisshy about the errorbar plot, maybe it's not true.

Comment: kevin, I suspect that is too old, but I don't know when the 'xkcd' colors were added to matplotlib (ping @tcaswell?).  Using `ecolor='xkcd:salmon'` works in matplotlib 2.0.2.

Comment: To fix it, use a different color, e.g. `ecolor='salmon'` might work.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser i will upgrade the version ... thnx .. it worked

Comment: Can one of you provide this as an answer, which can later be accepted such that this question does not stay unsolved? @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using an older version of matplotlib that does not have the 'xkcd' colors defined.  Using `ecolor='xkcd:salmon'` works in matplotlib 2.0.2. Either update matplotlib to a newer version, or use a different color (e.g. `ecolor='salmon'` should work).